# Parsing an AST with Boost::Spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, abstract-syntax-tree, boost-spirit

I would like to parse a language AST with Boost::Spirit.
When using Spirit parsing rules I get STL containers as attributes/result. I ideally would like to parse to custom AST objects with functionality related to language semantics and output to assembly.
What is the idiomatic way to do that with Boost::Spirit?

Comment: Here's an example from the [Spirit X3 docs](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/spirit/tutorials/rexpr.html) that demonstrates a simple parser with custom AST.

Comment: The question is way to broad. Start with the samples: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/  (for Qi) and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/example/x3/calc/ (for X3)

Comment: Thanks for the examples! Will take a look.

Comment: For the record, there are dozens upon dozens samples on this site. I know, because a fair number of them are by me :)

Comment: @sehe This example is not linked from the main documentation though. Is there a page listing all the examples?

Comment: It's in the archive when you download boost. Under `examples`

Comment: @sehe It would be nice to have an example section in the doc pointing at these.